# Inconsistent processing of search requests

Tags: support, comment

Linking through the [multiple-comparisons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-comparisons) tab gives a page listing 47 tagged questions (as of this moment).  The textbox in the upper right corner reads "[multiple-comparisons]".  Typing in another search term, such as "[multiple-comparisons] correlation" and pressing **Enter** *restricts* the search, in this case returning just 8 results.  The URL for these results is https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=[multiple-comparisons]+correlation.

However, using the *same* URL for a [link within a comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmultiple-comparisons%5D%20correlation) returns 390 search results!!

(If you link through the preceding line you will see 8 results.  If you link through the first comment below you will see all 390.)

Comment: [Here's a test](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=[multiple-comparisons]+correlation) `http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=[multiple-comparisons]+correlation`

Comment: [Here's another test.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmultiple-comparisons%5D%20correlation) `http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmultiple-comparisons%5D%20correlation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.

I get

https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmultiple-comparisons%5D%20correlation

8 results.

There are

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-comparisons

47 questions with the [multiple-comparisons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-comparisons) tag, so that doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: it's quite reasonable.  What's unreasonable is that *the very same URL* gives dramatically different results depending on whether it's used in a question/reply/Web browser or in a comment.  When you link through the test comment I provided, how many results appear for you?

Comment: oh you need to encode it. See the above version -- brackets have to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  That resolves it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it necessary to escape a *square* bracket when the quotation symbols are *parentheses*?

Comment: Seems like an obvious bug in the comment-processing code. Why wouldn't you also interpret brackets correctly for strings starting with **http://** and no white space in between. URL escaping is not likely to be well-known to users on specialized (non-SO) sites in the SE community.